# SQL update date field when it contains a specific hour/minute

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a little help in updating my DATE fields on my db.
I have to update every DATE field that has a date in which hour, minute and seconds are "00:00:00".
The format of the date is "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss".
First question: is there a way to do this?
Second question: how can it be done?
Thank you very much for the help!
EDIT: I need to update that field with the same date with only hour (and minute, and seconds) changed. Thanks

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` mysql clause will help

Comment: ***I need to update that field with the same date with only hour (and minute, and seconds) changed.*** To what value?

Comment: For example, I have 2013-03-19 00:00:00 --> I need to update with 2013-03-19 23:59:59 /// 2013-04-23 00:00:00 --> I need to update with 2013-04-23 23:59:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` MySQL function.

**Example**

```
UPDATE Table_Name set Field ='EDITVALUE'
   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dateField, "%h/%i/%s") = "00:00:00";
```

**Edit Answer**

You can use `CONCAT` MySQL function.

```
UPDATE Table_Name set dateField = CONCAT(date(dateField),' 05:12:50');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name
set column_name='your date'
where DATE_FORMAT(column_name, "%h/%i/%s") = "00:00:00"
```

OR in **sql server**

```
update table_name
set column_name='your date'
where 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), column_name, 14)='00:00:00'
```